# flux controller-view not subscribing for the event change in store

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-native, reactjs-flux, flux

I want to show a list of messages when the page is loaded. i call `action` and `addChangeListener` to subscribe for changes in `componentDidMount`, hoping i can get the data back from server from `store`, though `addChangeListener` is called, but the `callback` is not being invoked. It seems like `this.on('change', callback)` in `store` is not working as it should. does anyone know what is the issue of my code? Im following the example on flux's [repo](https://github.com/facebook/flux/tree/master/examples/flux-todomvc)

Also, where is the proper place to make api calls for backend data in store? is ok if i do it in getter in a store class?

thanks.

components/MessageList.js

```
class MessageList extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.renderMessage = this.renderMessage.bind(this)
    this.state = {

      loaded: false,
      dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
      })
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    messageActions.getAll()
    messageStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange)
  }


  _onChange() {
    console.log('on change') // <-- not being called from this point
    this.setState({
      dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(messageStore.getAll())
    })
  }

  //...
}
```

stores/MessageStore.js

```
let _messages = {}

function create(text, latitude, longitude) {

  fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/message', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      content: text,
      latitude: latitude,
      longitude: longitude
    })
  })
  .then(r => r.json())
  .then(data => {
    this.props.navigator.pop()
  })
  .done()
}


function getAllMessages(callback) {
  fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/message')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {

      callback(data)

    })
    .done()
}

class MessageStore extends EventEmitter {

  constructor() {
    super()

  }

  emitChange() {
    this.emit('change')
  }

  addChangeListener(callback) {
    console.log('here') // <-- works
    // this.on('change', callback) // <-- not working
    this.on('change', () => console.log('helloooo')) // <-- not working
  }

  getAll() {
    return _messages
  }

}

dispatcher.register(action => {

  switch(action.actionType) {

    case 'MESSAGE_CREAT':
      text = action.text.trim();
      if (text !== '') {
        create(text, action.latitude, action.longitude)
        messageStore.emitChange()
      }
      break
    case 'MESSAGE_ALL':
      console.log('store..');
      getAllMessages(data => _messages = data)
      messageStore.emitChange()

  }

})


const messageStore = new MessageStore()
export default messageStore
```

Comment: Have you set a dispatcher.dispatch method to trigger the change?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call the change listener in the store, you are only setting it up there. Try adding:

```
addChangeListener(callback) {
    this.on('change', callback);
}
```

Instead of:

```
addChangeListener(callback) {
   console.log('here') // <-- works
   // this.on('change', callback) // <-- not working
   this.on('change', () => console.log('helloooo')) // <-- not working
}
```

When a change happens, the changeListener in the store will trigger the change listener in MessageList:

```
messageStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange)
```

Then the _onChange function will be called.